# msfvenom: backdoored apk

Tags: android, metasploit, backdoor, msfvenom

I am using msfvenom to backdoor an Android apk. It is supposed that msfvenom adds extra permissions to original AndroidManifest:

```
[*] Poisoning the manifest with meterpreter permissions..
[*] Adding <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
[*] Adding <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
[*] Adding <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
[*] Adding <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
...
```

When I install the app in the Android phone, it just asks to allow default app permissions and not the injected ones.

Can anyone knows what can I do to edit the orignal apk code to ask for this permissions or how can I solve it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't modern Android versions wait until first use of a permission before prompting for approval?

Comment: After installing the app, at the first open, it requests for permissions, but only the default ones in the app. I tested with an file browser app and it only requested for file access permissions and not the injected ones (camera, microphone, etc...).